# Sqoop append not working for hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, bigdata

I tried to (CDC)append new data of a table from Teradata database to HDFS path of already moved old data.

`sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:teradata://xx.xx.xx.xx/database_name' --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager --username dbc --password dbc --query "select * from database_name.table_name WHERE (1=0 OR \$CONDITIONS) tymstp>'2016-07-28 04:49:53.44'" --fields-terminated-by '\t' --lines-terminated-by '\n' --target-dir /hdfs/path -m 1 --append`

Comment: Filealradyexists exception

Comment: It should not be a problem. As per docs, **If you use the --append argument, Sqoop will import data to a temporary directory and then rename the files into the normal target directory in a manner that does not conflict with existing filenames in that directory.**  Try this command with `--verbose` in the end to check extended logs and check if it first transferring to temporary location or not?

Comment: yes it is creating temp dir & moving data from  temp directory to target dir

Comment: after renaming? Then where do u get Filealreadyexists exception?